# how to send schdule sms in j2me?

Tags: java-me, sms, scheduling

i want to know how to send an sms at chosen time using j2me?I know how to send sms but unable to do it at chosen time by user using date field?

Comment: you already have code that works and code that doesn't? post them both here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [push registry](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/). The push registry lets you launch a MIDlet at a specified time, and that MIDlet can send the SMS.

Comment: Thanks!
I use the same concept but in my application i m using DateField where user enter the time and copy the time in
UserTime variable(UserTime = alarmTimeSetting.getDate().getTime(); )so it create a problem ..
But when i fixed UserTime = 30000(ms) it work properly.